# Translating object properties to readable text with the help of regex

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have different classes for different countries like China, USA, Japan, Mexico, Germany, etc. Now I am trying to create a detailed log summary each time an action is executed on the class (like clicking a button). So each time a button is clicked it will execute the **object** (example below) and save it to a database. How can I convert my object to the **desired outcome** as shown below?

Also, if I use `\n` to move to the next line, will it take more space in the database then just writing it all out onto one line? Is `\n` equivalent to writing a full line?

**Object:**

```
className{Id=StringProperty [value: 2xy], Name=StringProperty [value: Joe], Age=StringProperty [value: twenty], Hair=StringProperty [value: curly], Color=StringProperty [value: brown]}
```

**Desired outcome**

```
Id = 2xy,
Name = Joe,
Age = twenty,
Hair = curly,
Color = brown
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one:

```
(?:className{|, )(\w+?)=\w+ \[value: (\w+)(?:]}?)
```

Demo available at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uwyvSr/5) resulting output with `$1 = $2\n` substitution as:

```
Id = 2xy
Name = Joe
Age = twenty
Hair = curly
Color = brown
```

Description:

- `(?:className{|, )` is a non-capturing group before the name of the key
- `(\w+?)` captures the key to `$1`
- `=\w+ \[value:` matches literally the descriptional part between the key and the value. Ex. matches `=StringProperty [value:`
- `(\w+)` captures the value to `$2`
- `(?:]}?)` is a non-capturing group of the part after the value. Always ends with `]` and sometimes continues with `}`, so use the quotation operator `?` which matches the `0` or `1` occurencies.

---

Another and the less strict way ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7zaOXO/3)) is to capture keys between an empty space  or a curly bracket `{` and a square bracket `]` which is occasionally followed by an ending curly bracket `}`. But you have to mind the `className` anyway -> `.*?` at the beginning:

```
.*?(?: |{)(\w+?)=.*? \[value: (\w+?)](?:,|})
```

Comment: Hi @Nikolas is it possible to say to start from { and end with } so that we don't need to include the classname?

Comment: @Roger: Yeah: [`(?: |{)(\w+?)=.*? \[value: (\w+?)](?:,|})`.](https://regex101.com/r/7zaOXO/3) - I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer. It helped me a lot. Have a great day.